# Setting calendar unit month in swift increase the year

Tags: swift, swift2

The following code was supposed to set the current year to its first day:

```
import UIKit

private func getYearStartDate() -> NSDate {
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

    var date = calendar.dateBySettingHour(0, minute: 0, second: 0, ofDate: NSDate(), options: [])
    date = calendar.dateBySettingUnit(.Month, value: 1, ofDate: date!, options: [])
    date = calendar.dateBySettingUnit(.Day, value: 1, ofDate: date!, options: [])

    return date!
}

print("startdate=\(getYearStartDate())")
print("enddate=\(NSDate())")
```

But when I inspect it, the value is set to the first day of the NEXT year.

**My result:**

```
startdate=2017-01-01 02:00:00 +0000
enddate=2016-09-06 13:44:06 +0000
```

**Result I expect:**

```
startdate=2016-01-01 02:00:00 +0000
enddate=2016-09-06 13:44:06 +0000
```

Comment: So what value do you get? It gives  a correct result for me. Are you aware that `print(date)` prints the date in UTC and not in your local time zone?

Comment: I included the values in my question. The UTC in the `print` is not a problem, actually.

Comment: What is startdate, enddate? Please post a reproducible, self-contained example, including the print statements.

Comment: [`dateBySettingUnit`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCalendar/dateBySettingUnit:value:ofDate:options:) *can* change "higher" components, so yes, your approach can fail.

Answer (score 0):

The method `nextDateAfterDate:matchingComponents:options:` of `NSCalendar` is more suitable for that purpose, it can also search backwards for the past January 1st:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let components = NSDateComponents()
components.month = 1
components.day = 1
let yearStartDate = calendar.nextDateAfterDate(NSDate(), 
                             matchingComponents: components, 
                                        options: [.MatchNextTime, .SearchBackwards])
```